# Is it possible to skip NA values in "+" operator?

Tags: r, vector, sum, lapply, cbind

I want to calculate an equation in R. I don't want to use the function `sum` because it's returning 1 value. I want the full vector of values.

```
x = 1:10
y = c(21:29,NA)
x+y
 [1] 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 NA

x = 1:10
y = c(21:30)
x+y
 [1] 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40
```

I don't want:

```
sum(x,y, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 280
```

Which does not return a vector.

This is a toy example but I have a more complex equation using multiple vector of length 84647 elements.

Here is another example of what I mean:

```
x = 1:10
y = c(21:29,NA)
z = 11:20
a = c(NA,NA,NA,30:36)
5 +2*(x+y-50)/(x+y+z+a) 
 [1]       NA       NA       NA 4.388889 4.473684 4.550000 4.619048 4.681818 4.739130       NA
```

Comment: get the row wise sum of the concatenated vectors. `rowSums(cbind(x,y), na.rm = T)`

Comment: Ok, so you would put it in a data frame format. It's not possible to use them directly as vectors? `apply(cbind(x,y), 1, function(x) sum(x, na.rm = T))`

Comment: `cbind` creates matrixes, not data frames. `rowSums` is optimized and will be very quick, faster than `apply(..., 1, sum, na.rm = T)`.

Comment: *Skipping* NAs in a complex expression does not require to use a custom defined `+`. You can simply skip NAs in the final resulting vector e.g. `res<-res[!is.na(res)]` and that also avoid the risk to end up summing vectors of different length (in case of different number of NAs). If you want to *replace* NAs with zero instead, that's another story...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**1) %+%** Define a custom + operator:

```
`%+%` <- function(x, y)  mapply(sum, x, y, MoreArgs = list(na.rm = TRUE))
5 + 2 * (x %+% y - 50) / (x %+% y %+% z %+% a)
```

giving:

```
[1] 3.303030 3.555556 3.769231 4.388889 4.473684 4.550000 4.619048 4.681818
[9] 4.739130 3.787879
```

Here are some simple examples:

```
1 %+% 2
## [1] 3

NA %+% 2
## [1] 2

2 %+% NA
## [1] 2

NA %+% NA
## [1] 0
```

**2) na2zero** Another possibility is to define a function which maps NA to 0 like this:

```
na2zero <- function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)

X <- na2zero(x)
Y <- na2zero(y)
Z <- na2zero(z)
A <- na2zero(a)

5 + 2 * (X + Y - 50) / (X + Y + Z + A)
```

giving:

```
[1] 3.303030 3.555556 3.769231 4.388889 4.473684 4.550000 4.619048 4.681818
[9] 4.739130 3.787879
```

**3) combine above** A variation combining (1) with the idea in (2) is:

```
X <- x %+% 0
Y <- y %+% 0
Z <- z %+% 0
A <- a %+% 0

5 + 2 * (X + Y - 50) / (X + Y + Z + A)
```

**4) numeric0 class** We can define a custom class `"numeric0"` with its own + operator:

```
as.numeric0 <- function(x) structure(x, class = "numeric0")
`+.numeric0` <- `%+%`

X <- as.numeric0(x)
Y <- as.numeric0(y)
Z <- as.numeric0(z)
A <- as.numeric0(a)

5 + 2 * (X + Y - 50) / (X + Y + Z + A)
```

**Note:** The inputs used were those in the question, namely:

```
x = 1:10
y = c(21:29,NA)
z = 11:20
a = c(NA,NA,NA,30:36)
```

Comment: I was trying to find a way to use `mapply` and get four separate vectors (`X, Y, Z, A`). Out of curiosity, is it possible? (p.s. sorry for the edit, I saw a typo)

Comment: You can do this `attach(lapply(list(X = x, Y = y, Z = z, A = a), na2zero))` or `with(lapply(...), ...expression in X, Y, Z, A...)`

Answer (score 16):

***Using `rowSums`:***

To elaborate on my comment, you can *concatenate* the vectors and then apply your calculations on the resulted matrix. This is the solution for the example that you provided at the end of your question;

```
5 + 2 * (rowSums(cbind(x,y), na.rm = T)-50)/(rowSums(cbind(x,y,z,a), na.rm = T))

#  [1] 3.303030 3.555556 3.769231 4.388889 4.473684 4.550000 4.619048 4.681818 
#  [9] 4.739130 3.787879
```

***Repalcing `NA`:***

I have seen solutions here with the idea of replacing `NA` in the vectors; I think this would be helpful too:

```
y[is.na(y)] <- 0 #indexing NA values and replacing with zero
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use `ifelse()`

```
x = 1:10
y = c(21:29,NA)
x+y

[1] 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 NA

x + ifelse(is.na(y), 0, y)

[1] 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 10
```

Answer (score 7):

**DATA**

```
x = 1:10
y = c(21:29,NA)
x+y
# [1] 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 NA
```

**1**

```
foo1 = function(...){
    return(rowSums(cbind(...), na.rm = TRUE))
}
foo1(x, y)
# [1] 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 10
```

**2**

```
foo2 = function(...){
    Reduce('+', lapply(list(...), function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0)))
}
foo2(x, y)
# [1] 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 10
```

Comment: No need to go to `data.frame`, use `cbind()` instead to keep it as a matrix and avoid the extra conversions (`rowSums` will just convert back to a matrix).

Answer (score 5):

Just for laffs:

```
x=1:10
y=c(21:29, NA)

"[<-"(x, is.na(x), 0) + "[<-"(y, is.na(y), 0)
# [1] 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 10
```

which again illustrates the fact that everything in R is a function (and also shows that the R interpreter is smart enough to turn a string into a function when required).

Syntactically sweetened:

```
na.zero <- function(x)
{
    "[<-"(x, is.na(x), 0)
}
na.zero(x) + na.zero(y)
# [1] 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 10
```

More broadly applicable version:

```
na.replace <- function(x, value)
{
    "[<-"(x, is.na(x), value)
}
na.replace(x, 1) * na.replace(x, 1)
# [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```